# Nuget plugin doesn't print any logs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I created Class Library defined as `Windows Runtime Component` with one class:

```
using System;  
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public sealed class Snaggs
    {
        public void foo()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Hello Snaggs");
        }        
    }    
}
```

I created other project with reference to `ClassLibrary1` and I call it as:

```
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

        ClassLibrary1.Snaggs lib = new ClassLibrary1.Snaggs();
        lib.Foo();
    }
```

In logs I see: `Hello Snaggs`

So far so good.

Now I created basic `nuspec`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>AFDemoClassLibrary</id>
        <version>999.2.4</version>
        <authors>tester</authors>
    <owners>Maxim</owners>
    <description>This is a test</description>
     <licenseUrl>http://www.snaggs.test.com</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://www.snaggs.test.com</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>https://www.snaggs.test.com/logo.svg</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="bin\Release\**" target="lib\uap10.0" />
    </files>
</package>
```

I ran: `$ nuget pack AFDemoClassLibrary.nuspec`

And uploaded `.nupkg` file to `Nuget`

Now I created new project and installed this library with:

```
PM> Install-Package AFDemoClassLibrary
```

Got:

```
Successfully installed 'AFDemoClassLibrary 999.2.4' to TestClassLibrary1
```

Now I call this library again with:

```
ClassLibrary1.Snaggs lib = new ClassLibrary1.Snaggs();
lib.Foo();
```

**But don't get any output, I don't see `Hello Snaggs`**

This is output I got:

```
'TestClassLibrary1.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0_1.0.23819.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TestClassLibrary1.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\workspace\DEMOS\TestClassLibrary1\TestClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\entrypoint\TestClassLibrary1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'TestClassLibrary1.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\workspace\DEMOS\TestClassLibrary1\TestClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\System.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TestClassLibrary1.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\workspace\DEMOS\TestClassLibrary1\TestClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'TestClassLibrary1.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\workspace\DEMOS\TestClassLibrary1\TestClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TestClassLibrary1.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\workspace\DEMOS\TestClassLibrary1\TestClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\ClassLibrary1.winmd'. Symbols loaded.
'TestClassLibrary1.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\workspace\DEMOS\TestClassLibrary1\TestClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TestClassLibrary1.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\workspace\DEMOS\TestClassLibrary1\TestClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TestClassLibrary1.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\workspace\DEMOS\TestClassLibrary1\TestClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TestClassLibrary1.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\workspace\DEMOS\TestClassLibrary1\TestClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\System.Collections.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TestClassLibrary1.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\workspace\DEMOS\TestClassLibrary1\TestClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\System.Private.Uri.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

Where is my problem?

Maybe I have problem with my environment?

Try to install this plugin `AFDemoClassLibrary`

Thanks,

**[EDIT]**

Locally Im able to print logs.

Comment: I would try changing your .nuspec so it uses the Debug files instead of the Release ones. `<file src="bin\Debug\**" target="lib\uap10.0" />`.

Comment: Do you have the debug version of your package? In this case, the Debug files should be instead of the Release files. Have you also uploaded the .symbols.nupkg? After publishing your primary package to nuget.org, push the symbol package as follows, which will automatically use symbolsource.org as the target. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages

Answer (score 0):

Debug.WriteLine() works only for "Debug" builds (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz(v=vs.110).aspx)). When using "pack" command, without any options, it will generate a package from a Release build, without debug symbols or source files. Use the -symbols option in your nuget pack command to generate a debug package (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#pack)). This way you will see the logs.

Comment: it doesn't work. I still don't see any logs from module

Comment: Make sure you have the debug version of your package. In your local package folder you should see a src folder containing the source files.

Comment: Adding the -symbols parameter will generate an additional .nupkg file (<package>.symbols.nupkg). This one has to be uploaded to the server as well.

Comment: This is what I did.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` method only works under "Debug" configuration. Trying updating the code to：

```
Trace.WriteLine("Hello Snaggs");
```